# What is wrong with the given URL validation code in Java?

Tags: java

I know that better methods of URL validation exist and worse methods might be common that this example. But can someone tell me what is probably wrong with the following URL validation code when the url = "Some random english sentence" ?

I see that the validation fails. Dont know why.

```
/**
 * Checks if url is ok
 * THIS METHOD DOESNT SEEM TO WORK WELL
 * 
 * @param url
 * @return True if url is ok, False otherwise
 */
static public boolean isUrlOk(String url) {
    try {
        URL urlObject = new URL(url);
        String host = urlObject.getHost();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem: It sometimes returns true for random sentences.

Comment: what is the value of the exception?

Comment: anslo maybe try using org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html

Comment: `new java.net.URL("Some random english sentence")` fails for me, as expected.

Comment: What's the question here? You caught an exception which would have told you the answer, if you had bothered to print it, instead of reducing everything to 'true' or 'false'. Why are you asking us? And what makes you think it was a valid URL in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

modify the catch part to add e.printStacktrace() to get the details of why it fails.
If you are trying with "Some random english sentence" it will fail with no protocol specified.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `java.net.URL` API doc at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL(java.lang.String):

```
MalformedURLException - if no protocol is specified, or an unknown protocol is found, or spec is null.
```

Since no scheme was specified, the exception was thrown.